# Upload files to HTML form from Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

I want to know if there is any way to implement so that users can upload files on my website from their Google Drive account. I need to collect users school assignments, and right now I need them to export their Google Documents to PDF and then upload them. This requires an extra step, and I wonder if you can put a button instead on my website that says something like "Upload file from Google Drive", and they can click on it and choose which document to upload.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/picker

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! If you submit it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/picker to allow the user to choose the file. The picker returns a file ID, which you can then use with the Drive SDK to fetch the contents and ulpoad to your own server.